# Access Heroku MongoLab database from Rails application

Tags: html, ajax, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mlab

My Rails application is accessing MongoLab DB that has data loaded to it.
I am making a AJAX request to my DB. Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "mongodb://heroku_rgkq33fl:kbi2jctr39ts8gicrrchjuso5s@ds061954.mongolab.com:61954/heroku_rgkq33fl",
success: function(data){
    console.log("Success 1234"); 
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(data)
{
console.log("Error");
}       
})
}
```

I am not able to make a AJAX request because of the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load mongodb://heroku_rgkq33fl:kbi2jctr39ts8gicrrchjuso5s@ds061954.mongolab.com:61954/heroku_rgkq33fl. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Can someone please help me on how to get the data from my DataBase to my html page.

Comment: Why are you sending an AJAX request directly to a database? The URL you're trying GET isn't accessible if you paste it in your browser window, so it makes sense that your code doesn't work. You should have an app with an API endpoint to access the data you need. From a security perspective It is terrible idea to try to access a database via a HTTP get request.

Comment: Yea, you are right. I will instead access the DB from my Rails controller and make the AJAX request to the DB response found in the Controller. Thank you for the idea.